# Cordova open pdf in safari when saved

Tags: html, cordova

```
function saveData() {
                const customerData = {
                    customerName: document.getElementById('customerName').value,
                    orderNumber: document.getElementById('orderNumber').value,
                    storeNumber: document.getElementById('storeNumber').value,
                    date: document.getElementById('date').value,
                    // intallerID: document.getElementById('intallerID').value,
                    // intallerName: document.getElementById('intallerName').value,
                };
                const roomElement = document.getElementById(`room${windowSectionCounter}`);
                if (roomElement) {
                    roomElement.value = roomElement.value.toUpperCase();
                }
                const windowDataList = [];
                const windowSections = document.querySelectorAll('windowInfoSection');
                windowSections.forEach((windowSection, index) => {
                    // Add a check for null before accessing properties
                    const roomElement = windowSection.querySelector('input[name="room"]');
                    const quantityElement = windowSection.querySelector('quantity');
                    const mountElement = windowSection.querySelector('mount');
                    const widthElement = windowSection.querySelector('width');
                    const heightElement = windowSection.querySelector('height');
                    const depthElement = windowSection.querySelector('depth');

                    if (roomElement && quantityElement && mountElement && widthElement && heightElement && depthElement) {
                        const convertedWidth = convertDimensionsToFraction(parseFloat(widthElement.value));
                        const convertedHeight = convertDimensionsToFraction(parseFloat(heightElement.value));


                        const windowData = {
                            room: roomElement.value,
                            quantity: quantityElement.value,
                            mount: mountElement.value,
                            width: widthElement.value,
                            height: heightElement.value,
                            depth: depthElement.value,
                        };
                        windowDataList.push(windowData);
                    } else {
                        console.error('One or more elements in the window section are null.');
                    }
                });

                console.log('Customer Data:', customerData);
                console.log('Window Data List:', windowDataList);
                // Generate PDF
                const pdfData = {
                    customerData,
                    windowDataList,
                };

                generatePDF(pdfData);
            }    

            function generatePDF(data) {
                const addButton = document.getElementById('addWindowButton');
                const saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');
                const clearButton = document.getElementById('clearButton');
                const commentButton = document.getElementById('commentButton');
                const removeWindowButton = document.getElementById('removeWindowButton');
                const removeCommentButton = document.getElementById('removeCommentButton');

                addButton.style.display = 'none';
                saveButton.style.display = 'none';
                clearButton.style.display = 'none';
                commentButton.style.display = 'none';
                removeWindowButton.style.display = 'none';
                removeCommentButton.style.display = 'none';

                // Extract customer name and order number from the data
                const customerName = data.customerData.customerName;
                const orderNumber = data.customerData.orderNumber;

                // Convert spaces to underscores and remove any special characters
                const sanitizedCustomerName = customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g, '');
                const sanitizedOrderNumber = orderNumber.replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g, '');

                // Generate PDF with customer name and order number in the filename
                html2pdf().from(document.body)
                .set({
                    filename: `${sanitizedCustomerName}_${sanitizedOrderNumber}.pdf`,
                    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                    // html2canvas: { scale: 1.5 }, // Reduced scale
                    jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a3', orientation: 'landscape' },
                })
                .toPdf()
                .get('pdf')
                .then(function (pdf) {
                    const totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
                    pdf.setFontSize(10); // Set the font size for the page numbers
                    pdf.setTextColor(150); // Set the text color for the page numbers
                    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                        pdf.setPage(i);
                        pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + totalPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 30, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 5);
                    }
                })
                .save()
                .then(() => {
                    addButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    saveButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    clearButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    commentButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    removeWindowButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    removeCommentButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error generating PDF:', error);
                    addButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    saveButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    clearButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    commentButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    removeWindowButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    removeCommentButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                });
            }
```

Hello,

I have a html code that I have converted to app using cordova. In html when save button pressed it will convert everything to pdf and save it. when I have converted to app using cordova when I press saved it only opens a page but no option to save. all I need is when press saved on the app open the pdf on safari. I have tried lots of things but I can not figure it out. I have added plugins such as

cordova plugin add cordova-pdf-generator
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

any help much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: btw im using this app on iPad

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a blob from the generated PDF since you can't save it directly. Something like this:

```
function generatePDF() {
    html2pdf().from(document.body).toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(pdf.internal.stream.bytes);
        var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        cordova.InAppBrowser.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'location=no');
    });
}
```